# Weblogic console access behind Traefik proxy

Tags: weblogic, traefik

I have a Weblogic server, which is running behind Traefik proxy server. I was able to access the Weblogic admin console without any issue. The problem I am having is when I enter my credentials, I am getting **The username or password has been refused by WebLogic Server. Please try again**. But when I access the console directly using container ip, I was able to log in. That tells me something is wrong between Traefik and my Weblogic container.

Based on the Oracle article: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2419265_1.html, I tried setting the following Header **WL-Proxy-SSL=true**. Still I am seeing same issue.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my docker-compose file which I am testing locally.

```
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:1.7.18-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80" # The HTTP port
      - "443:443" # The HTTPS port
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.port=8081"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:docker.localhost"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml # Traefik configuration file
  weblogic:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/weblogic:12.2.1.3
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" # Enable reverse-proxy for this service
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:demo.docker.localhost"
      - "traefik.passHostHeader=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.headers.customRequestHeaders=WL-Proxy-SSL:true"
    ports:
      - 7001:7001
    volumes:
      - /Users/mtta/testing/properties:/u01/oracle/properties
    environment:
      DOMAIN_NAME: acme_domain
      DOMAIN_HOME: /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/acme_domain
      ADMINISTRATION_PORT_ENABLED: "false"
```

Comment: Login pages sometime use AJAX to send credentials. Check the AJAX op in your browser's network panel to see if the request is sent, and what the response contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the following:

1. Set the RequestHeader WL-Proxy-SSL to true.
2. Enable WebLogic Plug-In in the Weblogic console. Here is the link on how to enable the plugin: https://www.ateam-oracle.com/wls-plugin-enabled

Once these settings are in place, console login works behind the loadbalancer with SSL.